# Is the output anova(test='Chisq') and an anova(test='LRT') when comparing logistic regression fits?

Tags: logistic, anova

I have to run LRT to compare two logistic regression models. when I run the code below I noticed the output seems identical. In this scenario are these identical tests? If so in what scenario would they be different?

```
input_null <- mtcars[,c("am","cyl","hp")]
null_fit <- glm(formula = am ~ cyl + hp, data = input_null , family = binomial)

input_full <- mtcars[,c("am","cyl","hp", "wt")]
full_fit <- glm(formula = am ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = input_full , family = binomial)


chisq <- anova(null_fit, full_fit, test='Chisq')
lrt <- anova(null_fit, full_fit, test='LRT')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation for `?anova.glm`.

> You can also choose "LRT" and "Rao" for likelihood ratio tests and
> Rao's efficient score test. The former is synonymous with "Chisq"
> (although both have an asymptotic chi-square distribution).

`"LRT"` and `"Chisq"` are synonymous; they both trigger the same calculations.